# Can methods of objects be called from ABAP debugger script?

Tags: debugging, scripting, abap

I'm just discovering the new (to my system) ABAP Debugger Script.

Say this is my program:

```
* Assume i have the class LCL_SMTH with public methods INCREMENT and REFRESH

DATA: lo_smth TYPE REF TO lcl_smth.

CREATE OBJECT LO_SMTH.    
lo_smth->increment( ).

WRITE 'Nothing hapenned'.
```

Could i get my script to call the REFRESH method after it exits INCREMENT?

I set the script to execute on calling of the INCREMENT method, and it does so. Next I know I have to STEP OUT (F7) -> which I also do - i just don't know how to invoke the REFRESH method.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Debugger script can do exactly what you could do manually. So you can't ... unless you could manually. Since you can jump manually in the debugger, debugger script can as well. So if there is a suitable call to REFRESH somewhere in the code, then you can jump there and back as well.